# I need to write test cases for external API without calling it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
describe ":PUT, '/v1/workday/update_candidate_assessment', ::Assess Candidate API" do
    it "# 3. example" do
      put "/api/v1/workday/update_candidate_assessment", params: {
        api_key: "dsfds",
        data: {
          client_id: "r53535",
          campaign_id: "R5343",
          assessed_on_date: "2021-06-10",
          candidate_id: "6353636",
          assessment_test_reference: "View1",
          assessment_status_reference: "Status",
          assessment_score: "10",
          assessment_status_id: "rsgshs"
        }
      }
      puts JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).size).to eq(3)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to have_key("body")
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to have_key("description")
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to have_key("message")
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["message"]).to include("Success")
    end
  end
```

The above code calling update_candidate_assessment API in my application after It will call external API.

I need to write test case which will return fake response.I don't want to call external API.

Comment: Hi Chetan, you can use this https://github.com/bblimke/webmock. This allows you to stub HTTP requests. Another option is to use VCR gem https://github.com/vcr/vcr. It will allow you to record your HTTP interaction in a file called cassettes. Then you can write a test against that response. Note VCR will call API in the first attempt then all subsequent calls will point to the relevant file(cassette).

Comment: Just adding on here. The coolest thing about VCR in my opinion is that any time you want to hit the real API, just delete the cassette file and re-run the test.